# Number of answers of equation amongs odd natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, combinations

How many answer The following Equation has, in set of odd natural numbers?

$x_1+x_2+...+x_k=n$,    $k \equiv^2 n$

Solution: Comb ( [(n+k)/2]-1,  k-1), comb means combination. how we get this?

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of $k \equiv^2 n$ ?

Comment: Ok, normally this is written $k \equiv \pmod 2$

Comment: But I think you mean $n \equiv k \pmod 2 $

Comment: Ah, I see. And for combinations one writes $$a \choose b$$

Comment: And I suppose that the order is unimportant, that is permuting the numbers doesn't make a new solution. Moreover I suppose zeroes are also excluded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17622/discussion-between-nimda-and-davied-zuhraph).

Comment: Please edit the question to include additional context, such as the setting where you encountered the question and what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $k$ is odd and $n$ is even, there are no solutions in odd integers. Similarly, if $k$ is even and $n$ is odd, there are no solutions in odd integers. So we may assume that $n$ and $k$ have the same parity (both odd or both even).

The number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$ in odd positive integers is the number of solutions of $y_1+\cdots+y_k=n+k$ in even positive integers. For we go from odd integers $x_i$ to even positive integers $y_i$ by adding $1$ to each $x_i$, and the process is reversible.

Similar reasoning shows that the number of solutions of $y_1+\cdots+y_k$ in even positive integers  is the same as the number of solutions of $z_1+\cdots+z_k=\frac{n+k}{2}$ in positive integers.

By standard Stars and Bars, there are $\binom{\frac{n+k}{2}-1}{k-1}$ solutions of $z_1+\cdots+z_k=\frac{n+k}{2}$ in positive integers.

**Remark:** Alternately, the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$ is the number of solutions of $v_1+\cdots+v_k=n-k$ in non-negative even integers (subtract $1$ from each $x_i$, which is the same as the number of solutions of $w_1+\cdots+w_k=\frac{n-k}{2}$ in non negative integers. Stars and Bars deals with this problem.